Evaluation in recommendation system
I want to calculate the precision, recall, and f1-score values of the recommendation system that I built. I plan to conduct an evaluation by asking users directly whether the recommendation items given are relevant or not. If there are several users who are the object of evaluation, how do I calculate the precision, recall, and f1-score of these users simultaneously?
I want precision, recall, and f1-score values that are aggregated from all users.
